# Переписать jquery на нативный JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как будет выглядеть жикверный скрипт на нативном JS?

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $( ".dotted" ).each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            $(this).next('.rekl-close').toggle();
        });
    });


    $( ".rekl-close" ).each(function() {
        $(this).find('.rekl-button').click(function() {
            $(this).parent('.rekl-close').toggle();
        });
    });


    $('.popup-c section button').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
            navigator.clipboard.writeText($(this).prev('.token').text())
                .then(() => {
                    // Получилось!
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Something went wrong', err);
                });
        });
    });
})
```

Comment: [You might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll(".dotted").forEach(function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var nextReklClose = element.nextElementSibling;
            if (nextReklClose && nextReklClose.classList.contains('rekl-close')) {
                nextReklClose.style.display = (nextReklClose.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
            }
        });
    });

    document.querySelectorAll(".rekl-close").forEach(function(element) {
        var reklButton = element.querySelector('.rekl-button');
        if (reklButton) {
            reklButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                element.style.display = (element.style.display === 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
            });
        }
    });

    document.querySelectorAll('.popup-c section button').forEach(function(button) {
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var tokenElement = button.previousElementSibling;
            if (tokenElement && tokenElement.classList.contains('token')) {
                var tokenText = tokenElement.textContent || tokenElement.innerText;
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(tokenText)
                    .then(function() {
                        // Success!
                    })
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.log('Something went wrong', err);
                    });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Прикольно! Спасибо!